# BroadcastReceiver class not running

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I wrote a `BroadcastReceiver` class for receiving a broadcast intent when charger is disconnected but it does not display the Toast when I disconnect the charger.
The Logcat does not show anything either. I use ADB over wifi.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class My extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sumitaich.sunsick"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/hacker"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <receiver
        android:name=".My">

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sumitaich.sunsick.POWER_CONNECTED" />
       </intent-filter>

</receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Detail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName="com.sumitaich.sunsick.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.sumitaich.sunsick.MainActivity" />
    </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action in android manifest to :

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
```